# Restore Previous Versions of Files From Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rsync

We used GCS for our offsite backup and it has been working great.
However, one of our office computers got infected with a randsomware virus over the weekend and encrypted all of our shared network files. The thing is our backup script does an rsync every evening and syncs up our shared network files which means that all the live versions of the files on GCS are now the encrypted randsomware files.

We use versioning and keep 4 versions of all files. Is there a way to restore the version previous to the live version of all the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify the situation posted in the question was just a hypothetical that I had been curious about trying to answer ever since moving over to using GCS as our offsite backup.

It seems the only way to achieve the desired result of trying to restore in this situation is to use some scripting to get a file list of files that meet the date requirement. What I found was that google's generation ID is a unix epoc timestamp in microseconds (NOT Milliseconds). This is much easier to use as a date comparison than trying to parse the timestamp as Mike suggested. I did however end up using `gsutil ls` to get the file list to parse as it's just quick and easy.

Once you have the file list to restore using your script you can feed that into

`cat restoreList.txt | gsutil cp -m -I /restore-location`

Since I'm a bit of a brainlet JS junkie I decided to write my script using Node.js even though using something like Python would be just as easy.

```
const fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.readFileSync('./inputList.txt', 'utf8');

var regex = /(gs:.*)#(\d*)/;
var fileList = {};

// Make sure and remember that JS Dates use the 0-11 notation for months so Feb = 1
// Also google generation IDs are in microseconds so we need to multiply by 1000
const beforeThisDate = new Date(2018, 1, 8, 5, 30).getTime() * 1000;

file.split('\n').forEach(line => {
  var found = line.match(regex);
  if(!found) return;
  var fileName = found[1];
  var fileEpoc = found[2];
  var fullPath = found[0];
  if(!fileList[fileName] && fileEpoc < beforeThisDate) {
    fileList[fileName] = {fileEpoc, fullPath};
    return;
  }
  if(fileList[fileName] && fileEpoc < beforeThisDate && fileList[fileName].fileEpoc < fileEpoc) {
    fileList[fileName] = {fileEpoc, fullPath};
    return;
  }
  return;
})

Object.keys(fileList).forEach(key => {
  console.log(fileList[key].fullPath);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no option for rsync to do that automatically. You would need to list all versions of your objects (using `gsutil ls -a`) and then pick the second most recent from each.

Comment: Mike, what would be your suggestion for trying to build a file list and parsing that list to select the files that I would want to restore. Using `gsutil ls` seems like a somewhat inefficient way to do this.

Comment: Ian - if you're concerned about the efficiency of doing it using gsutil ls, you could write a tool that calls the API directly (specifying versions=true -- see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list), selects the second newest of each object (by examining timeCreated), and outputs that list. You could then turn the list into a script that calls gsutil cp on each.